# How to customize error message in swagger when mandatory fields value are not sent in API?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-editor

Below is my api.yml:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
    title: 'AutoDelievery API'
    description: 'AutoDelievery API Documentation'
    termsOfService: 'https://www.yopmail.com'
    contact:
        name: yopmail
        url: 'http://www.yopmail.com'
        email: contactus@yopmail.com
    license:
        name: yopmail
        url: 'http://www.yopmail.com/licenses/yopmail-AutoDelievery-Licence.html'
    version: 1.0.0-oas3
servers:
    -
        url: 'http://localhost:5055/'
tags:
    -
        name: AutoDelievery
        description: 'AutoDelievery product related APIs'
        externalDocs:
            description: 'Documentation:'
            url: 'http://localhost:5055/external/doc'
paths:
    /autoDelievery:
        post:
            tags: [autoDelievery]
            summary: 'Creates a new autoDelievery record'
            operationId: insertSubscription
            requestBody: {description: 'autoDelievery request body', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelievery'}}}}
            responses: {'200': {description: 'successful operation', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelievery'}}}}, '400': {description: 'Bad Request', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelieveryError'}}}}, '500': {description: 'Server Error', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelieveryError'}}}}}
    '/autoDelievery/{autoDelieveryID}':
        get:
            tags: [AutoDelievery]
            summary: 'AutoDelievery as per ID'
            description: 'Fetches the AutoDelievery for the provided Id'
            operationId: getAutoDelieveryById
            parameters: [{in: path, name: autoDelieveryID, required: true, schema: {type: string}}]
            responses: {'200': {description: 'successful operation', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelievery'}}}}, '400': {description: 'Server Error', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelieveryError'}}}}}
        delete:
            tags: [autoDelievery]
            summary: 'Delete AutoDelievery as per ID'
            description: 'Finds the autoDelievery for the provided Id and deletes the same'
            operationId: deleteAutoDelieveryById
            parameters: [{in: path, name: autoDelieveryID, required: true, schema: {type: string}}]
            responses: {'200': {description: 'successful operation', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelievery'}}}}, '400': {description: 'Server Error', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelieveryError'}}}}}
    '/autoDelievery/{autoDelieveryID}/payment':
        put:
            tags: [AutoDelievery]
            summary: 'Updates autoDelievery payment details'
            parameters: [{in: path, name: autoDelieveryID, description: 'AutoDelievery Id of which payment details are to be updated', required: true, schema: {type: string}}]
            operationId: updatePayment
            requestBody: {content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/PaymentMethod'}}}}
            responses: {'200': {description: 'successful operation', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelievery'}}}}, '400': {description: 'Bad Request', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelieveryError'}}}}, '500': {description: 'Server Error', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelieveryError'}}}}}
    '/autoDelievery/{autoDelieveryId}/frequency':
        put:
            tags: [AutoDelievery]
            summary: 'Updates AutoDelievery frequency, quantity and end data.'
            parameters: [{in: path, name: autoDelieveryId, description: 'AutoDelievery Id of which frequency is to be updated', required: true, schema: {type: string}}]
            operationId: updateFrequency
            requestBody: {content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/Frequency'}}}}
            responses: {'200': {description: 'successful operation', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelievery'}}}}, '400': {description: 'Bad Request', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelieveryError'}}}}, '500': {description: 'Server Error', content: {application/json: {schema: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelieveryError'}}}}}
components:
    schemas:
        SubscriptionList:
            type: object
            properties: {count: {type: integer}, result: {type: array, items: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/AutoDelievery'}}, page: {type: integer}}
        DataEntity:
            type: object
            properties: {id: {type: string}, lastModifiedDate: {type: string}, createdDate: {type: string}}
        AutoDelievery:
            allOf: [{$ref: '#/components/schemas/DataEntity'}, {type: object, required: [userId, clientId, quantity, frequency, payment, product, shippingAddress], properties: {userId: {type: string}, clientId: {type: string}, parentSubscriptionId: {type: string}, product: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/Product'}, quantity: {type: integer, minimum: 1}, frequency: {type: number, minimum: 1}, payment: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/PaymentMethod'}, paymentMethodId: {type: string}, shippingMethodId: {type: string}, nextOrderDate: {type: string}, subscriptionStartDate: {type: string}, subscriptionEndDate: {type: string}, shippingMethod: {type: string}, shippingAddress: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/Address'}}}]
        Product:
            type: object
            required: [productId]
            properties: {productId: {type: string}, productDescription: {type: string}}
        PaymentMethod:
            type: object
            required: [billingAddress]
            properties: {createdDate: {type: string}, modifiedDate: {type: string}, paymentType: {type: string}, billingAddress: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/Address'}}
            discriminator: {propertyName: paymentType}
        Frequency:
            type: object
            required: [frequency, quantity]
            properties: {frequency: {type: number, minimum: 1}, subscriptionEndDate: {type: string}, quantity: {type: integer, minimum: 1}}
        Card:
            allOf: [{$ref: '#/components/schemas/PaymentMethod'}, {type: object, required: [nameOnCard, lastFourDigits, expiryMonth, expiryYear], properties: {nameOnCard: {type: string}, lastFourDigits: {type: string}, token: {type: string}, expiryMonth: {type: string, minLength: 2, maxLength: 2}, expiryYear: {type: string, format: year}}, discriminator: {propertyName: paymentType}}]
        PayPal:
            allOf: [{$ref: '#/components/schemas/PaymentMethod'}, {type: object, required: [accountId], properties: {accountId: {type: string}}}]
        Payment:
            type: object
            properties: {payment: {allOf: [{$ref: '#/components/schemas/PaymentMethod'}], discriminator: {propertyName: paymentType}}}
        Address:
            type: object
            required: [firstName, lastName, addressLine1, city, state, postalCode, country]
            properties: {prefix: {type: string}, firstName: {type: string}, middleName: {type: string}, lastName: {type: string}, suffix: {type: string}, title: {type: string}, companyName: {type: string}, addressLine1: {type: string}, addressLine2: {type: string}, city: {type: string}, state: {type: string}, postalCode: {type: string}, country: {type: string}, phoneNumber: {type: string}, mobilePhoneNumber: {type: string}}
        Status:
            type: object
            required: [status]
            properties: {status: {type: string}, details: {type: string}}
        Shipping:
            type: object
            properties: {shippingMethodId: {type: string}, shippingMethod: {type: string}}
        PaymentAuthorization:
            type: object
            properties: {authId: {type: string}}
        CommerceItem:
            type: object
            required: [subscriptionId, quantity, product]
            properties: {subscriptionId: {type: string}, product: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/Product'}, quantity: {type: number, minimum: 1}, itemUnitPrice: {type: number}, itemTotalPrice: {type: number}, itemDiscount: {type: number}}
        ErrorResponse:
            type: object
            required: [errorMessage]
            properties: {field: {type: string}, errorMessage: {type: string}}
        ErrorResponseList:
            type: object
            required: [errors]
            properties: {errors: {type: array, items: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse'}}}
        NoSubscriptionResponse:
            allOf: [{$ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorResponseList'}]
        AutoDelieveryError:
            allOf: [{$ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorResponseList'}]
        NoOrderResponse:
            allOf: [{$ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorResponseList'}]
```

my sample api is:

```
  "id": "string",
  "lastModifiedDate": "string",
  "createdDate": "string",
  "userId": null,
  "clientId": "string",
  "parentSubscriptionId": "string",
  "product": {
    "productId": "string",
    "productDescription": "string"
  },
  "quantity": 0,
  "frequency": 0,
  "payment": {
    "createdDate": "string",
    "modifiedDate": "string",
    "paymentType": "string",
    "billingAddress": {
      "prefix": "string",
      "firstName": "string",
      "middleName": "string",
      "lastName": "string",
      "suffix": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "companyName": "string",
      "addressLine1": "string",
      "addressLine2": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "state": "string",
      "postalCode": "string",
      "country": "string",
      "phoneNumber": "string",
      "mobilePhoneNumber": "string"
    }
  },
  "paymentMethodId": "string",
  "shippingMethodId": "string",
  "nextOrderDate": "string",
  "subscriptionStartDate": "string",
  "subscriptionEndDate": "string",
  `enter code here`"shippingMethod": "string",
  "shippingAddress": {
    "prefix": "string",
    "firstName": "string",
    "middleName": "string",
    "lastName": "string",
    "suffix": "string",
    "title": "string",
    "companyName": "string",
    "addressLine1": "string",
    "addressLine2": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "state": "string",
    "postalCode": "string",
    "country": "string",
    "phoneNumber": "string",
    "mobilePhoneNumber": "string"
  }
}
```

I get an error response in the following format:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": "userId",
            "errorMessage": "must not be null"
        }
    ]
}
```

What should I do to have a customized error message?

Comment: Did u get a resolution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Swagger puts `@NotNull` annotation on `required` fields while creating POJO.

[Message interpolation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-message-interpolation) can be done by creating `ValidationMessages.properties` file in the classpath as follows:

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=CUSTOMIZED ERROR MESSAGE
```

It will override the default error message which comes from

```
/org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily solved by adding a ControllerAdvice class. Figure out the exception being thrown from the stacktrace and write a handler for the same. In the handler you will be able to throw custom error messages, when ever this kind of exception occurs.

Here is some reference for [ExceptionHandler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_exception_handling.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement spring's abstract class OncePerRequestFilter and override
doFilterInternal method .
Inside this method add validation using httpservletRerquest and return the custom message using ResponseStatusException .
ref- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-onceperrequestfilter

Answer (score 0):

As far as I researched, OpenApi does not have a built-in mechanism to override the validation messages. However, you can achieve this using the `x-field-extra-annotation` extension to add custom or other annotations to the property fields.

```
components:

  schemas:
    #...

    Address:
      type: object
      required: [firstName, lastName]
      properties:
        email:
          type: string
          x-field-extra-annotation: "@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull(message = \"your custom message\")"
        firstName:
          type: string
        lastName:
          type: string
```

To add more validator annotations, simply put them on the same line,

```
x-field-extra-annotation: "@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull(message = \"your customer message\") @javax.validation.constraints.Email(message =\"Emil must be valid\")"
```

---

Note: For **spring boot 3.x** or **jakarta-validation**, use `jakarta` instead of `javax`.